# Windows Server 2008 with FileZilla, slow

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

First post on this site. Seems like a nice place. ^__^

Well, installed Windows Server 2008 as our dev server. 
IIS works as it should, the remote desktop with TightVNC works but lags 
and I need to refresh everything all the time. 
But the real issue is with our ftp.

We're trying to use FileZilla. Connecting locally works great but when I try to connect from the same place using the external ip everything goes slow.

I can connect so the port must be open correctly but I can't do anything useful.
When I open a folder to check what's inside it takes one or two minutes to get the folder open.

Any ideas why it's like this?

Cheers,
nandarya.

Comment: Does it show the same behavior in both Active and Passive FTP modes?

Comment: Totally off topic, but why are you using VNC instead of the built-in RDP which is *much* faster?

Answer (score 1):

What's your WAN connection like?  Firewall?  You might want to put Wireshark on the machine with FileZilla to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've configured the built in Windows Server 2008 firewall to allow FTP through. Remember FTP is one of those problematic two-way protocols, so it takes a bit more effort to get it set up.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/309/configuring-ftp-firewall-settings/

commands to open the firewall to typical (non-secure) FTP:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="FTP (non-SSL)" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=21  
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFtp enable
```